Proving $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ba^2 + ac^2 + cb^2$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $ab + bc + ac = 3$
Given $a, b, c > 0$ such that
$$ab + bc + ac = 3$$
we need to prove that:
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ba^2 + ac^2 + cb^2$$
Attempt or Context:

Start by noting the given condition $ab + bc + ac = 3$ implying $a+b+c >= 3$
Consider possible algebraic manipulations or inequalities that could help, such as AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, or rearrangement inequalities.
I have tried to homogenize the inquality but with no success yet.

Question:
How can we proceed to prove the inequality $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ba^2 + ac^2 + cb^2$ under the given condition?

From Vasile inequality
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \geqslant 3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a).$$
Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2 \leqslant 3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)(ab+bc+ca) \leqslant (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2(ab+bc+ca).$$
Thus
$$3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2 \leqslant (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2(ab+bc+ca).$$
Now, for the conditon $ab+bc+ca=3,$ then
$$(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)^2 \leqslant (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2,$$
or
$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \leqslant a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

Very nice application of Vasc's inequality. Thank you so much!!!
